# DexieJS return NotFoundError in a nested query

Tags: dexie

I am facing an issue on DexieJS when i had a nested query. The following is the sample of my code:-

```
    let id = 1;

    let child = db.child.where({ id : result.child_id }).first( item => item ).catch( e => "NotFoundError"; );
    console.log(child); // success, it shows the child item

db.parent.where({ id : id }).each( parent => {
  let child = db.child.where({ id : parent.id }).first( item => item ).catch( e => "NotFoundError"; );
  console.log(child); // it will show NotFoundError
});
```

no idea of what is happening, does nested query not working on DexieJS which i have no doubt it should work.

Please advice, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution or workaround, it is working now.

```
await db.transaction('r', db.parent, db.child, async () => {
  await db.parent.where({ id : id }).each( async parent => {
    let child = db.child.where({ parent_id : parent.id }).first( result => result );
    console.log(child) // *now it shows the child record
  });
});
```

Looks like we need to use transaction to have query within a query result.
I hope this is the right way and hope this help.
Please do not hesitate to comment if this is not the right way.

Nameste.

Comment: It's an ok solution. The reason you need this is that each() fires off its callback within an implicit readonly transaction containing only db.parent. What actually happens is that db.child is not part of the transaction. However, I would advocate to use toArray() rather than each() for both simplicity and performance. See https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.each()#notes

Comment: @DavidFahlander Thank you for the advice, it works and should be better. I thing that still crack me is the following code that it doesn't return the result.
console.log( db.table.where( { id : id }).first( result => result );
it always return some De { _listener ........
how can i get the object in result? thanks in advance

Comment: What you pass to console.log() is a promise. You have to await it or else reverse the code to db.table.where({id: id}).first(result => console.log(result))